# ListNode's next field type to Option<Box<ListNode>>, is it correct?

Tags: rust

I tried to resolve https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers, this problem is easy while I cannot finish it in rust because of borrow problem. I tried several 3 hours and I doubt `ListNode`'s `next` field type to `Option<Box<ListNode>>` is not properly.

When I switch to c#, I finish the problem quickly. Following is c# version solution. I am unable to translate it to rust.

```cs
public class Solution {
    public ListNode AddTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode re = null;
        ListNode next = null;
        int carry = 0;
        while(l1 != null || l2 != null) {
            var val = (l1 != null ? l1.val : 0) + (l2 != null ? l2.val : 0) + carry;
            carry = val / 10;
            val %= 10;
            if (re != null){
                next.next = new ListNode(val);
                next = next.next;
            } else {
                re = new ListNode(val);
                next = re;
            }
            if (l1 != null) {
                l1 = l1.next;
            }
            if (l2 != null) {
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            next.next = new ListNode(carry);
        }
        return re;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Option<Box<ListNode>>` sounds plausible as part of a linked list in Rust, but you'll need to show some code if you want help debugging whatever problem you ran into. Be aware that linked lists are not trivial and Rust will force you to justify yourself in a lot of ways that C# doesn't; see https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/#learn-rust-with-entirely-too-many-linked-lists for detailed instructions and explanations.

Comment: Recursive types are tricky in Rust because of borrowing issues, as you noted. If the type does not provide iterators or other helper types, you have two options that I know of: unsafe code or recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @rodrigo suggestion. I finally resolve the problem in recursive function way.

```rust
fn internal_add_two_number(
    mut l1: &Option<Box<ListNode>>,
    mut l2: &Option<Box<ListNode>>,
    mut carry: i32,
) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut sum = carry;
    if l1.is_none() && l2.is_none() {
        if carry > 0 {
            return Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(carry)));
        }
        return None;
    }
    if let Some(p) = l1 {
        sum += p.val;
        l1 = &p.next;
    }
    if let Some(p) = l2 {
        sum += p.val;
        l2 = &p.next;
    }
    carry = sum / 10;
    sum = sum % 10;

    Some(Box::new(ListNode {
        val: sum,
        next: internal_add_two_number(l1, l2, carry),
    }))
}

impl Solution {
    pub fn add_two_numbers(
        l1: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
        l2: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
    ) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        internal_add_two_number(&l1, &l2, 0)
    }
}
```